# Image changes only after a major delay on most mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css, image, mobile, delay

I wonder why changing an image of an existing element via image `src` tag or css `background-image` is only done after a great delay on most mobile browsers. (Android Chrome, iOS Chrome, iOS Safari, ...)

I basically have either an image tag or a div and I want to change the image instantly:

```
// preload images
for(var i = 1; i < 21; i++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "covers/" + i + ".jpg";
}

var cover = $("#cover");
$("#flow").on("touchstart", function(){
  p++;
  cover.src = "covers/" + p + ".jpg";
  // cover.style['background-image'] = "url('covers/" + p + ".jpg')";
});
```

Both methods work great on desktop browsers and also on the native Android browser. I created an [example here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/889313/flowAnim/change-src.htm) (You need to touch down to change the src of the image tag - you can do so in Chrome browser by selecting the `Emulate touch events` in the Web Inspector). In iOS 6 and 7, both Safari and Chrome the changing does not occur immediately but with a significant delay. Same for Android Chrome.

The images all are preloaded (Safari Web Inspector Remote Debugging also says so). The behaviour does not change when the images are preloaded via image tag with `display: none;`.

Can you imagine why?

Comment: Most browsers don't load images in <img> tags in a `display: none;` region. Have you tried loading them in a tiny region that is 1px x 1px off screen that is something like: `position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px;`?

Comment: My guess is that image data you preload is removed from memory because `Image` objects are garbage-collected almost immidiately. This is not an issue on desktop because of much larger amounts of available memory. Try keeping `Image`s in array in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to watch out for the server `Cache-Control` header.

I test served the page from a Dropbox to view on different devices. Dropbox currently does not allow its served resources to be cached by the browser. This means, a good browser MUST check back with the server for a newer version before applying it (defined in the [RFC 2616 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1)).

So all versions with JS preloading, image tag preloading, css background-image or image tag src work perfectly once the browser is not forced to check back. This can be done by having the server respond with a cache control header of `Cache-Control: public`.

Thanks for any other approaches!